# What happens when your MVC/Web API isn't async top to bottom?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

So in a typical Web API async action we have something like this:

```
[ HttpGet ]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReturnSomeStuff() {
        ...
        }
    }
```

Now, what if my actual Web API action isn't async, just a normal method, but I still used async-things, and maybe just call the `Result` property on the `Task` to return the result.

**What benefits would I missing-out on by not having the whole action async from top to bottom?**

Comment: Microsoft provides a very thorough explanation of what happens within an async method, have a read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: What you'd miss the the confidence that your code won't deadlock.

Answer (score 5):

In short, avoid this at all costs and instead use async from top to bottom. What you propose will almost certainly create deadlocks since this is an ASP.NET application. Read up on much of what Stephen Cleary has written on this topic before you go any further:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, [using `Request` will open up your code to a deadlock situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (described in full on my blog). This is because `await` will by default resume its `async` method on a captured context. On ASP.NET, this context is generally the ASP.NET request context, which only allows one thread in at a time. If a higher-level method blocks a thread (by calling `Task<T>.Result`), then it's blocking that context, and the `async` method cannot use that context to continue execution. So the thread ends up waiting for the task to complete while the task is waiting for the thread to release the request context, and you get a deadlock.

But to answer your actual question:

> What benefits would I missing-out on by not having the whole action async from top to bottom?

Almost all of them.

Most benefits of `async` code go out the window as soon as you block. Even if you avoid the deadlock issues (which is possible, but not recommended), then you would still lose the primary benefit of asynchronous code, which is *scalability*. Asynchronous code is more scalable because it releases the thread pool thread back to the thread pool; if the code blocks, then it doesn't release the thread. Simple as that.

You *could* say that there are still minor benefits to asynchronous code in that the asynchronous code is more maintainable and reusable (say, if it were part of a library). Or that asynchronous concurrency would be easier to code. These would be valid arguments, but are very weak benefits compared to the primary benefit of async code (scalability), which is irrevocably lost as soon as you block.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we can say, it is about reusing threads. (scaling cpu usage right?)

When you await an async method, if any network or io bound code is running in that method, the thread, executing the async method, can be reused by other requests (not blocking the executing thread). Also if you do not await that method it runs in another syncronization context asynchronously untill you await it.

Calling Result of the Task returned by an async method, will block the current thread also (that means that thread can not be used during the execution of an external web request i.e.)

Note that when your method is doing CPU bound work only, do not make it async, because it is worthwhile, making the current thread busy for a cpu bound work. But still your CPU bound method without async keyword can return a type of Task so that it can be awaited in an async method (but not running in another synchronization context).

Also you can do something like:

```
    public async Task<Data> MakeWebRequest(string resource)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task<DataCollected> CollectData()
    {
        var result = new DataCollected();
        var task1 = MakeWebRequest("/data/x");
        var task2 = MakeWebRequest("/data/y");
        var task3 = MakeWebRequest("/data/z");

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
        result.data1 = task1.Result;
        result.data2 = task2.Result;
        result.data3 = task3.Result;
        return result;
    }
```

So that the 3 web requests are made without blocking eachother. On the other hand when your app is waiting the http response, it can use current thread for other stuff.

Comment: In the context of an ASP.NET application using .Result in this manner will do more than block the calling thread...it will cause a full deadlock.

Comment: cool, i did't know that deadlock case. thanks.

Comment: @SamStorie Can you explain why it will cause a full deadlock?

Comment: @Sam.Rueby Sure. It's because the ASP.NET request context only allows a single thread in at one time. So when your task tries to resume execution (via the use of .Result) it tries to access the request context. However, that context is occupied by the thread that spawned the task, and thus you're stuck. Neither thread can continue because they're waiting for each other.